# Node-oidc-provider How to store clients in database

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid, openid-provider

I have a problem with node-oidc-provider.

I want the client list to be stored in the database, but I haven't found a solution.

Please help me!!!

Comment: i have same problem, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

For storing clients in the database, you can make use of below link to store the clients as well as other tokens

https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/example/adapters/contributed/sequelize.js

For creating tables, you can use below link

https://github.com/roggervalf/node-oidc-provider/tree/examples/example/migrations/sequelize

Comment: This is not true. DCR does not have to be enabled at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your client definitions stored in a DB, just have your adapter for the Client model respond to the `find(id)` invocation.

https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/docs/README.md#clients

> In addition to these clients the provider will use your adapter's find method when a non-static client_id is encountered.